# Simplify URL rewrites in .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)$ /userviewproducts.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/$ /userviewproducts.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)$ /userviewproducts.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/$ /userviewproducts.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)$ /viewbuyproduct.php?1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/$ /viewbuyproduct.php?1=$1 [L]
```

I have next rules. 
They work in that way:

```
if url = /a or /a/ or /a/a or /a/a/ go to file userviewproducts.php
and if url = /a/a/a or /a/a/a/ go to file viewbuyproduct.php
```

It works as i need, but i see the CODE-SMELLS term here and want to write it shorter. 
Will plus every answer =)

Comment: Anyway I belive these type of questions should be posted on Stackoverflow. You are gonna get more valuabel answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ /userviewproducts.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ /userviewproducts.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+/[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ /viewbuyproduct.php?1=$1 [L]
```

It's shorter.

Comment: Whoops, I left the page open for 20 minutes and ended up posting the same answer as you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info).  A better understanding of them will help you write shorter rules here and in future.

You can use a [regular expression tool](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html) to experiment with different rules and see how they match.

I am sure you can get it down to two lines - one for each outcome that you want.  The lines might be longer though :-)

Answer (score 0):

This could be further simplified to:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+(/[\w-]+)?)/?$ /userviewproducts.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/[\w-]+/[\w-]+)/?$ /viewbuyproduct.php?1=$1 [L]
```

`\w` is shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

The `-` (hyphen) does not need to be escaped when used at the start or end of the character class.

The `?` at the end makes the preceding slash optional.

Finally, the first two rules (substitutions) are combined by making the second part of the pattern optional. ie. `(/[\w-]+)?`. `$1` still matches the whole URL-path, less the trailing slash (if any).